# Software to assist in upgrade from win7 to win 10

Tags: windows

I've been avoiding the migration for some time but i think now is the time to move to win10 from my working win7.
I have many programs and setting which i would like to migrate if possible.

Is there a tool which can assist in this?
e.g. same most program settings and help after i reinstall them in the new operating system?

I know i can upgrade my win7 to win10 but it is always advisable to preform a clean install.

Thanks,

Comment: Back up your data and do a fresh install - really is the best way.  Heck, hard drives are cheap enough, just get a new one.  Use your current one with a USB adapter to make it an external so you can copy what data files you want back.  Might want to post over on superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is any software for that.

One option is creating a backup by simply copying the folders C:\Users , C:\Program Files, C:\Program Files (x86) and every Program / File installed directly inside C:\ to your external (flash-) drive.

Don't forget to also copy important device drivers to it.

If there is enough storage available, I'd say [Dual Booting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-booting) is the option.

One way to do this by creating a partition with Disk Management located here: C:\Windows\System32\diskmgmt.msc .

Then you can use both operating systems whenever you want.

I would still recommend you creating a backup.

I hope this answer helped you out!

Comment: i do not want to upgrade - it's better to perform clean install.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more relevant to your question.